# MyBatis XML and Spring configuration

Tags: spring, mybatis

I'm using mybatis mappers (XML) and spring configuration. To run the segments of sql, I've setup `vendorProperties`, `datasource` and `sqlSessionFactory` (included databaseIdProvider). Additionally, provided `databaseId="oracle"` in the mapper. The mappers are configured in mybatis-config file.
When I run the service, I see error message even though the mapper namespace and the `SQL` fragment id matches with the name.

```
"Invalid bound statement (not found):"
```

Mapper config:

```
<select id="getNextId" resultType="java.lang.Integer" databaseId="db2"> SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR TBL1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 </select> 
<select id="getNextId" resultType="java.lang.Integer" databaseId="Oracle"> SELECT TBL1.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL </select>
```

AppContext.xml:

```
<bean id="vendorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
  <property name="properties"> 
    <props> 
      <prop key="DB2">db2</prop> 
      <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop> 
      <prop key="H2">h2</prop> 
      <prop key="MySQL">mysql</prop> 
    </props> 
  </property> 
</bean> 
<bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" destroy-method="clearCache"> 
  <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory"/> 
</bean>
```

Also AppContext.xml contains databaseIdProvider bean:

```
<bean id="databaseIdProvider" class="org.apache.ibatis.mapping.VendorDatabaseIdProvider"> 
  <property name="properties" ref="vendorProperties"/> 
</bean> 
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mappers/mybatis-config.xml"/>
  <property name="databaseIdProvider" ref="databaseIdProvider"/> 
</bean>
```

Can someone help to identify why I keep getting "Invalid bound statement (not found)" error when the query related to getNextId is parsed?

Comment: Please provide some sample what you've done, its easier for the users to answer your question properly.

Comment: Mapper config:<select id="getNextId" resultType="java.lang.Integer" databaseId="db2">
  SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR TBL1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
 </select>

 <select id="getNextId" resultType="java.lang.Integer" databaseId="Oracle">
  SELECT TBL1.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
 </select>

Comment: AppContext.xml:  <bean id="vendorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="DB2">db2</prop>
                <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop>
                <prop key="H2">h2</prop>
    <prop key="MySQL">mysql</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate"
          destroy-method="clearCache">
        <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Also AppContext.xml contains databaseIdProvider bean: 
  <bean id="databaseIdProvider" class="org.apache.ibatis.mapping.VendorDatabaseIdProvider">
        <property name="properties" ref="vendorProperties"/>
    </bean>

 <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation"
                  value="classpath:mappers/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="databaseIdProvider" ref="databaseIdProvider"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Can someone help to identify why I keep getting "Invalid bound statement (not found)"  error when the query related to getNextId is parsed  ?

Comment: My mybatis-spring version is 1.2.1 and mybatis version is 3.2.3 in case if it is helpful

Comment: add significant details to the question itself not to the comments